# Windows touchpad damaged

Tags: windows, boot, touchpad

While I was making my bootable DVD for Fedora 18 with another laptop, after finishing, I wanted to try whether it worked or not. So I restarted my system. It worked, so I've turned the installation process off took my DVD and started the installation process on my laptop. However, on the first one my touchpad started not working. I must mention I had installed Windows 7 on it, and the laptop is Dell Vostro 1500. The left and right click works, but the rest of it doesn't. How could I restore that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you haven't just disabled it. Many laptops have a function key for that or sometime double tapping the top left corner.

Comment: sure, I haven't done that

Comment: Is it broken in both os fedora and windows?

Comment: on that laptop I have only Windows.

Comment: I meant when you booted from the live dvd.

Comment: oh, sorry, I misunderstood, the answer is yes.

Comment: That would make me think it's either disabled in the bios or broken. Hopefully it's just disabled.

Comment: and how could I check in BIOS whether it is disabled or not?

Comment: I'm not sure where it might be in the dell bios, I've never owned a dell but your usually looking for a section called device options or device configuration.

Comment: I've reinstalled its driver and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do, installation process for what?

Under the assumption that you're installing Windows, I'd say download Touchpad drivers and install them.

Comment: sorry, I've omitted this, I've edited my question.